# Uses for 1-to-1 Non-Identifying Relationship

Tags: sql

There has been many questions regarding identifying versus non-identifying relationships, however, they all focus on 1-to-many relationships.  Below is my present understanding, and please correct me if I am wrong.

If the parent's key is part of the child's PK, it is an identifying relationship.  This means that a record in the child table cannot exist without a corresponding record in the parents table (a book cannot exist without an author), and the parent's PK is required to uniquely identify a record in the child table (obviously, since it is part of the child PK).

1-to-1 Identifying Relationships are similar.  An example would be a transmissions table, automatic_transmissions table, and manual_transmissions table, where automatic_transmissions table and manual_transmissions both have a 1-to-1 identifying relationship to transmissions.  Each automatic_transmissions table and manual_transmissions table must have an associated transmission, and the transmissions PK can uniquely identify any associated record in the automatic_transmissions table or manual_transmissions table.  This approach is used because automatic_transmissions table and manual_transmissions table both share many attributes, but each also has attributes specific to themselves.

Am I okay until now?

Now take a 1-to-1 Non-Identifying Relationship.  What, a table with no PK?  Why would one need such a table?  What are some examples?  How is it used?

Comment: You know the part where you ask if you are ok until now?  I don't think so.  I think you have your parents and children messed up.  For example, while you can't have a book without an author, you can have an author without a book.  In this scenario, the parent is the author and the child is the book.  The book table would have an authorID (unless you made it many to many), but an author table would not have a bookID.

Comment: @DanBracuk.  I agree.  That whole parent/child part messes me up.  But I do understand the part about how the book table would have an authorID column.  I just changed my original post based on your advise.

Comment: Now I see the term, "Non-Identifying Relationship" as an oxymoron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a table of cars and a table of transmissions.  Each car has one transmission.  Each transmission is only in one car at a given time.  However, the same transmission doesn't always stay in the same car.  Sometimes a car's transmission breaks and has to be replaced.  Sometimes a transmission gets taken out of an old, broken-down car and put into a different one.

There is a one-to-one relationship between cars and transmissions.  However, it is a non-identifying relationship, because the child's (transmission) identity doesn't depend on the parent (car).

None of this implies "a table with no PK".  Both the cars and transmissions tables would have primary keys.  It's just that the PK for car is not part of the PK for transmission.